# Add To Favorite Button in a Listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I have a listeView,each listeView Item have "add to favorite" button ,what I want to do is whenever the user click favorite button this listView Item will be added to a Favorite listview (Im using fragments).what I did is add this code to my custom adaptor getview methode :

```
 final Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    final Button favorite = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
    favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            currentWord.setFavorite();
            favoritewords.add(currentWord);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ringtone Added To Favorite List", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }
    });
```

Now I want to send this favoritewords arraylist of word objects to the favorite list fragment , is it possible ?? if not please is there any other solution ??

Answer (score 1):

It's better to just add the item listener on the `ListView`

```
ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);
List<long> favoriteWordIds = new ArrayList<>();

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            favoriteWordIds.add(l);
            // Then use the ids to access them from database or somewhere
        }
    });
}
```